# Opening GML file with collection of geometries in QGIS

Tags: qgis, import, gml, data-interoperability, geometrycollection

I can't visualize in QGIS the `.gml` file [that can be downloaded here](https://ckan.open.nrw.de/dataset/8d1aeb86-b515-451f-bc28-55fa6029e0f9) (second row). I think QGIS doesn't support files with `'collection of geometries'`, therefore I don't know how to use it.

A professor of mine opened it with ArcGIS Pro and he could open it with the interoperability tool. Then he sent me only the polygons layer but the attribute table was corrupted, and many important fields were missing. Now sadly he can't help me anymore. I managed to get ArcGIS Pro but I'm having big trouble downloading the data interoperability tool, which seems required to open such as type of dataset.

Could anyone support me in some way?

The possible solutions could be:

- Open the file in QGIS separating polygons from points and lines
- Downloading in someway the data interoperability tool and fixing the problem by myself
- Could someone download, open and end and send me the polygons layer with the correct attribute table?

Answer (score 5):

That Inspire data has features which are hard for QGIS.

- some attributes are lists, like this: habitatSpecies|HabitatSpeciesType|localSpeciesName|LocalNameType|localName (StringList) = (4:Alnus glutinosa,Filipendula ulmaria,Petasites hybridus,Phalaris arundinacea)
- geometries are saved as GeometryCollections like here:

  GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (MULTIPOLYGON (((50.5835012882546 6.34620799321084,50.5834108662349 6.34637668101145,50.5833565080047 6.34651748589854,50.5833380218919 6.3467009176975,50.5833461705137 6.34698344297107,50.583282571035 6.34718057196579,50.5832728156011 6.34746297321249,50.583245162907 6.34767446905424,50.5831989489811 6.348097796692,50.5832060081818 6.34874728504048,50.5831247718793 6.34884551757273,50.5831159792777 6.34880306274709,50.5829675080357 6.34734775787077,50.5829319004802 6.34720622059219,50.5829504017334 6.34705104546741,50.5828702069725 6.34679630841888,50.5828973501788 6.34674010742382,50.5829514037828 6.34671220295574,50.5830420901847 6.34644460737573,50.5831864383121 6.34626215100823,50.5833665801176 6.34615043944333,50.5835012882546 6.34620799321084))))

Most geometry collections contain just one MultiPolygon and because of that it is rather easy to get most of the features to show in QGIS. Convert the data into GeoPackage and convert GeometryCollections into MultiPolygons. Conversion fails if a GeometryCollection has also other geometries (points, linestrings) but 44733 features gets converted.

```
ogr2ogr -f gpkg habitats.gpkg FFH-LRT_Vorkommen_NRW_EPSG4258.gml -nlt multipolygon
```

[image]

Comment: Opening in HALE shows that there are 44773 features in the dataset